# How can I build a flagging system for posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've been trying to figure out the best way to build out a user flagging system in rails 3.1. I experimented with the `make_flaggable` gem, but it didn't give me what I needed.

I'm using devise for my user model and I have a Post model that belongs to the user. I need to have the ability to retrieve a list of all posts that have been flagged from the admin side of the site. So far, I've had difficulty obtaining that.

I'm uncertain about which type of relationship I would need to use between a Flag model and the Post/User model. I've been reading up on Polymorphic relationships and that is looking promising.

Any ideas or feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you read the sample of using, and do accoring that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's very easy to roll your own solution. I would do it this way.

```
class User 
  has_many :flags
end
class Post 
  has_many :flags
end
class Flag
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

You can get posts that have been flagged by going through the flag model or the post model.

```
# since a post has many flags
# you will get duplicates for posts flagged more than once
# unless you call uniq
flagged_posts = Post.joins(:flags).uniq
```

Or through the flags model:

```
flags = Flag.includes(:post).uniq
flags.each do |flag|
  puts flag.post
end
```

To ensure you don't get duplicate flags on the same post from the same user I would add a uniq index in the migration:

```
  def change
    create_table :flags do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, null: false
      t.belongs_to :post, null: false
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :flags, [:user_id, :post_id], unique: true
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but why not just add a column to your Posts table called "flagged?"  Then you can just do User.posts(:where=> :flagged=>true).